# How to solve the import problem when using pytest?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, import, pytest

I can't run my tests through pytest. And I have a strong belief that this is an imports issue. The project structure looks like in the attachment.
In the root directory there is a file contest.py with a driver start and close fixture

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

@pytest.fixture
def browser():
    """Fixture for initializing webdriver"""
    print("\nStarting browser for test...")
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    yield browser
    print("\nClosing browser...")
    browser.quit()
```

Test methods are described in the base_page.py file, which is located in the pages folder

```
from .locators import BasePageLocators

class BasePage:
   
    def __init__(self, browser, url, timeout=10):
        self.browser = browser
        self.url = url
        browser.implicitly_wait(timeout)

    def open(self):
        self.browser.get(self.url)

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try:
            self.browser.find_element(how, what)
        except:
            return False
        return True
    
    def should_be_sign_up_button(self):
        assert self.is_element_present(*BasePageLocators.SIGN_UP, "No Sign Up button on the page")

    def open_sign_up_modal(self):
        self.browser.find_element(*BasePageLocators.SIGN_UP).click()
        assert self.is_element_present(*BasePageLocators.CREATE_ACCOUNT_H2, "Sign Up modal is not open")
```

There is a file with locators (locators.py) in a same folder

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class BasePageLocators():
    SIGN_UP = (By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Sign Up']")
    CREATE_ACCOUNT_H2 = (By.XPATH, "//h2[text()='Create Your Account']")
```

And a file with tests (tase_base_page.py) in the tests folder

```
from pages.base_page import BasePage

link = "https://somelink.com/"

class TestSignUp():

    def test_see_sign_up(browser):
        page = BasePage(browser, link)
        page.open()
        page.should_be_sign_up_button()

    def test_open_sign_up_modal(browser):
        page = BasePage(browser, link)
        page.open()
        page.open_sign_up_modal()
```

Every time I run the tests, I get the error "AttributeError: 'TestSignUp' object has no attribute 'implicitly_wait'". But if I remove this method, another error appears, and so it is every time: if I fix one thing, another error appears.

When using the command "pytest --fixtures" from the "tests" folder, the "browser" fixture, which is defined in the conftest.py file, is not output.

I tried creating another project with one test, running it through pytest: the message that no tests were run was displayed, although the browser instance was running.

Asked ChatGPT - useless, implemented all tips - no use

Moved the project directory to the C drive

Added/removed points before imports

Reinstalled pytest, etc.

Help me, please! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `self` arg in your test methods

e.g.

```py
    def test_see_sign_up(self, browser):
        page = BasePage(browser, link)
        page.open()
        page.should_be_sign_up_button()
```

At the moment you have:

```py
    def test_see_sign_up(browser):
        page = BasePage(browser, link)
        page.open()
        page.should_be_sign_up_button()
```

This means that instead of receiving the `browser` fixture value, you have just given your self arg a different name.

So then when you instantiate the `BasePage` you are passing the test class instance as `browser` var.

Which is why you get *AttributeError: 'TestSignUp' object has no attribute 'implicitly_wait'* when the `BasePage` instance calls `browser.implicitly_wait(timeout)`.

Self arg is required when defining test cases inside a test class. Alternatively you could just define them as module functions without being inside a class, e.g.

```py
def test_see_sign_up(browser):
    page = BasePage(browser, link)
    page.open()
    page.should_be_sign_up_button()

def test_open_sign_up_modal(browser):
    page = BasePage(browser, link)
    page.open()
    page.open_sign_up_modal()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, but unfortunately it didn't solve the problem to the end.

Now I get the error "fixture 'browser' not found"

If you run "pytest --fixtures" from the tests folder, it doesn't show up in the available ones.
If you run the same command from the root of the project, it shows up.
What can this be related to? As far as I know, the conftest.py file should be inspected by pytest every time the tests are run. I don't have any other conftest.py files anywhere else

Comment: If the `conftest.py` is above the dir you are running the tests from then pytest won't find it. You should just run tests from the root of the project, you don't need to cd into tests/ to run them

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped. But is it not possible to keep the tests in a separate "tests" folder? It seems more structured to me

Comment: yes, keep the tests in a `tests/` folder... you don't have to cd into that folder to run the tests (pytest will find them, you can also pass an explicit path to pytest cli)